# How to Use Firebase Polyfills in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, polyfills

I'm currently building a vanilla webpage that uses Google Firebase to handle both [Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) and data storage, using the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database). This is how I am including Firebase, at the bottom of my HTML file:

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.4.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.4.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

This all works fine and dandy in most browsers. However, in Internet Explorer, it throws various errors about not having certain es6 functions, most frequently `Array.findIndex` and `Object.values`.

The Firebase [supported environments](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/environments_js-sdk#polyfills) page says that polyfills are required -- fair enough. However, I'm unclear how to include the recommended "[ES Stable](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/tree/master/packages/core-js/stable)" into a vanilla html/js page, as all their examples involve bundlers or frameworks.

I'm looking for an example or explanation of how to include this, or any polyfill that solves the problem, into a regular HTML/JS page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking over the `core-js` [installation section](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#installation), it looks like they do provide a CDN that you could attach. The exact text is this:

> Already bundled version of core-js on CDN (minified version).

The CDN they are referring to is [here](https://unpkg.com/core-js-bundle@3.2.1/index.js), and the minified version is [here](https://unpkg.com/core-js-bundle@3.2.1/minified.js).

Comment: Wow, don't know how I missed this. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below polyfill that only contains es6 feature. I have faced the same issue while working with firebase and resolved with below polyfill.

Just load below script to your plain JavaScript project with firebase (all versions) will work fine.

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
```

> You can find the direct CDN (minified version) link [here](https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=es6).